# C++ Unordered Map

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, unordered-map

I have a program in which I am using an iterator to get access to a value of a map entry .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int a[]={1,2,4,7,9,3,3,55,66,88,11};
   int k = 58;
   unordered_map<int,int> c;
   int i=0;
   for(auto x: a)
   {
       c.insert(make_pair(x,i));
       i++;
   }

   for(auto x: c)
   {
     if(c.count(k-x.first)==1) printf("%d %d\n",x.second,(c.find(k-x))->second);
   }

}
```

In the line:

```
if(c.count(k-x.first)==1) printf("%d %d\n",x.second,(c.find(k-x))->second);
```

I am getting errors especially in `c.find()->second`. I think it is the way to access elements from the iterator. What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot say

```
c.find(k-x)
```

Because `k` is an `int` and `x` is a `std::pair<int, int>`. Do you mean one of these two?

```
c.find(k - x.first)
```

Or

```
c.find(k - x.second)
```

As a side note, it is generally unsafe to directly derefernce the returned iterator from `find` because if `find` returns `.end()` (as in, it didn't find an element with that key) then you've got a problem.

Comment: Yes I did that in count , forgot in find. Thanks a lot.